# MSSQL and ALTER AUTHORIZATION on table has no affect?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, schema

I have a schema called [test] with an owner X.

I transferred an ownership of one table [test].[table] (ALTER AUTHORIZATION) to owner Y.

Now, if I understand correctly, even though the owner X owns the parent schema [test], he/she should have no access to [test].[table] since an owner of that table is Y, correct?

Or must I explicitly `DENY` permissions to X on that table?

I tested this and owner X still has an access to [test].[table].

And btw, X is not member of `db_datareader` or `db_owner` ;-)

So the question is, what is the purpose of `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` on an object/table if other users still have access to it (regardless if they are owners of parent schema)?

Best,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following quote should explain what is going on

"Ownership of schema-contained objects can be transferred to any database-level principal, but the schema owner always retains CONTROL permission on objects within the schema."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189462(v=sql.105)

Comment: Makes sense, somehow I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen Morris suggested, ownership implies CONTROL permission and SQL permission are hierarchical. So the schema owner also has CONTROL (full) permissions on the schema-contained entities.

> So the question is, what is the purpose of ALTER AUTHORIZATION on an
> object/table if other users still have access to it (regardless if
> they are owners of parent schema)?

One use case for changing the authorization on a specific object so that the schema owner isn't inherited is to intentionally break the ownership chain. For example, if all objects are in the dbo schema and a particular table has especially sensitive data, you could change the owner of that table to a user without a login. That will prevent inadvertently allowing access to the table via ownership chaining in dbo-owned procs, views, or functions; only callers with permissions on the table (including inherited permissions) can access the table (barring certificate signing.

Comment: That was exactly my aim, to prevent access to a sensitive data in couple of the tables in a schema. I am still not sure how to achieve that. Let's say I have two users. a User and a SuperUser. SuperUser should have have access to the whole schema, while User to all tables except for the sensitive ones. So I think I should make SuperUser an owner of the schema, set the owner of the sensitive table(s) to a user without login and give explicit read permissions to schema to a User, right?

Comment: I would have DBO own the schema and grant SELECT on the schema to User and SuperUser, and DENY select to User.  That way the permissions are all handled through GRANTs, and DBO retains the ability to provide restricted access the sensitive data in views or stored procedures.

Comment: @MikeU, if only db_owner members can create objects, do as David suggested so that security administration is easier. If SuperUser needs to create objects in the schema, SuperUser needs at least ALTER permission on the schema too. Also, if your grant CONTROL permissions on the schema to SuperUser, You don't need to grant additional permissions on schema to SuperUser.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I did just that and whilst the table is now hidden from User, that User can still select from views on that table. I was hoping to break the ownership chain and automatically prevent access to all views on that table. As is now, the schema owner owns the table and the views so I need to identify and and access control all views. Not ideal.

Comment: @MikeU, to also prevent the inadvertent ownership chaining, you need to also change the table owner as I mentioned in my answer. Alternatively DENY permissions on objects that expose data from the table if you've granted permissions a a higher scope.